# Unexpected redux action result

Tags: javascript, redux

I was hired to make a couple of features and fixes in an existing app. There are a few lines of code which makes me confused.

An action dispatched in component:

```
export function getCategory() {
  const request = axios({
    method: "get",
    url: url,
  }).then(response => {
    return {
      data: response.data.results,
    };
  })
  console.log(1, request)
  return {
    type: types.GET_CATEGORY,
    payload: request,
  };
}
```

and reducer:

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CATEGORY:
      console.log(2, action.payload)
      return {
        ...state,
        category: action.payload.data
      };
    ...
```

I expected to have unresolved promise in both console.log 1 and 2.
Actually console.log 1 prints resolved promise and console.log 2 prints data received from the server.

[image]

Redux works synchronously and there are no async/await keywords in getCategory function. Why reducer gets proper data and not unresolved promise?

App details: react-native, redux with only thunk middleware.
(please don't give me advice about thunks, sagas, etc. It's not my code)

EDIT

Problem solved, other programmer added redux-promise middleware and I was not added to review...

Comment: There should be something else. Are you sure about "only thunk middleware" part?

Comment: It is the task of Thunk to handle the `async - await`. Thunk halts action dispatch until promise is resolved, and then dispatches the action with the resolved payload to the reducer.

Comment: OMG @YuryTarabanko someone added redux-promise middleware. I didn't see that. Solved...